# How can I send the "SCAN_RESULT" to another activity with zxing in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, zxing

How can I put the result of the QR "SCAN_RESULT" in different activity, this is my problem.

In the splash screen I need to go to the QRScanner (CaptureActivity), and then, to the ActivityQR who will send the info. to the SQLite.

The problem is: When I get de QRCode in string ("SCAN_RESULT") on "CaptureActivity.java", the app close because the app need "back" to the previous activity with this:

```
getIntent();
```

I try to modify this codeline, but this not solve my problem.

How can I put the "SCAN_RESULT" in the ActivityQR? I don't know how open other activity (this case ActivityQR) when the code had gottenm and put this String value on the ActivityQR

I Use "CaptureActivity" of ZXing (ZebraCrossing)

Thanks in advance.

SplashScreen.java :

```
{

Intent mainIntent = new Intent().setClass(SplashScreenActivity.this, com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.class);
startActivity(mainIntent)

}
```

ActivityQR.java

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(REQUEST_CODE == requestCode && RESULT_OK == resultCode){

        txResult.setText(data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"));

    }
}
```

CaptureActivity.java

```
    public class CaptureActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

      private static final String TAG = CaptureActivity.class.getSimpleName();

      private static final long DEFAULT_INTENT_RESULT_DURATION_MS = 1500L;
      private static final long BULK_MODE_SCAN_DELAY_MS = 1000L;

      private static final String[] ZXING_URLS = { "http://zxing.appspot.com/scan", "zxing://scan/" };

      public static final int HISTORY_REQUEST_CODE = 0x0000bacc;

      private static final Collection<ResultMetadataType> DISPLAYABLE_METADATA_TYPES =
          EnumSet.of(ResultMetadataType.ISSUE_NUMBER,
                     ResultMetadataType.SUGGESTED_PRICE,
                     ResultMetadataType.ERROR_CORRECTION_LEVEL,
                     ResultMetadataType.POSSIBLE_COUNTRY);

      private CameraManager cameraManager;
      private CaptureActivityHandler handler;
      private Result savedResultToShow;
      private ViewfinderView viewfinderView;
      private TextView statusView;
      private View resultView;
      private Result lastResult;
      private boolean hasSurface;
      private boolean copyToClipboard;
      private IntentSource source;
      private String sourceUrl;
      private ScanFromWebPageManager scanFromWebPageManager;
      private Collection<BarcodeFormat> decodeFormats;
      private Map<DecodeHintType,?> decodeHints;
      private String characterSet;
      private HistoryManager historyManager;
      private InactivityTimer inactivityTimer;
      private BeepManager beepManager;
      private AmbientLightManager ambientLightManager;

      ViewfinderView getViewfinderView() {
        return viewfinderView;
      }

      public Handler getHandler() {
        return handler;
      }

      CameraManager getCameraManager() {
        return cameraManager;
      }

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        setContentView(R.layout.capture);

        hasSurface = false;
        historyManager = new HistoryManager(this);
        historyManager.trimHistory();
        inactivityTimer = new InactivityTimer(this);
        beepManager = new BeepManager(this);
        ambientLightManager = new AmbientLightManager(this);

        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
      }

      @Override
      protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // CameraManager must be initialized here, not in onCreate(). This is necessary because we don't
        // want to open the camera driver and measure the screen size if we're going to show the help on
        // first launch. That led to bugs where the scanning rectangle was the wrong size and partially
        // off screen.
        cameraManager = new CameraManager(getApplication());

        viewfinderView = (ViewfinderView) findViewById(R.id.viewfinder_view);
        viewfinderView.setCameraManager(cameraManager);

        resultView = findViewById(R.id.result_view);
        statusView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_view);

        handler = null;
        lastResult = null;

        resetStatusView();

        SurfaceView surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.preview_view);
        SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        if (hasSurface) {
          // The activity was paused but not stopped, so the surface still exists. Therefore
          // surfaceCreated() won't be called, so init the camera here.
          initCamera(surfaceHolder);
        } else {
          // Install the callback and wait for surfaceCreated() to init the camera.
          surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        }

        beepManager.updatePrefs();
        ambientLightManager.start(cameraManager);

        inactivityTimer.onResume();

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        copyToClipboard = prefs.getBoolean(PreferencesActivity.KEY_COPY_TO_CLIPBOARD, true)
            && (intent == null || intent.getBooleanExtra(Intents.Scan.SAVE_HISTORY, true));

        source = IntentSource.NONE;
        decodeFormats = null;
        characterSet = null;

        if (intent != null) {

          String action = intent.getAction();
          String dataString = intent.getDataString();

          if (Intents.Scan.ACTION.equals(action)) {

            // Scan the formats the intent requested, and return the result to the calling activity.
            source = IntentSource.NATIVE_APP_INTENT;
            decodeFormats = DecodeFormatManager.parseDecodeFormats(intent);
            decodeHints = DecodeHintManager.parseDecodeHints(intent);

            if (intent.hasExtra(Intents.Scan.WIDTH) && intent.hasExtra(Intents.Scan.HEIGHT)) {
              int width = intent.getIntExtra(Intents.Scan.WIDTH, 0);
              int height = intent.getIntExtra(Intents.Scan.HEIGHT, 0);
              if (width > 0 && height > 0) {
                cameraManager.setManualFramingRect(width, height);
              }
            }

            String customPromptMessage = intent.getStringExtra(Intents.Scan.PROMPT_MESSAGE);
            if (customPromptMessage != null) {
              statusView.setText(customPromptMessage);
            }

          } else if (dataString != null &&
                     dataString.contains("http://www.google") &&
                     dataString.contains("/m/products/scan")) {

            // Scan only products and send the result to mobile Product Search.
            source = IntentSource.PRODUCT_SEARCH_LINK;
            sourceUrl = dataString;
            decodeFormats = DecodeFormatManager.PRODUCT_FORMATS;

          } else if (isZXingURL(dataString)) {

            // Scan formats requested in query string (all formats if none specified).
            // If a return URL is specified, send the results there. Otherwise, handle it ourselves.
            source = IntentSource.ZXING_LINK;
            sourceUrl = dataString;
            Uri inputUri = Uri.parse(dataString);
            scanFromWebPageManager = new ScanFromWebPageManager(inputUri);
            decodeFormats = DecodeFormatManager.parseDecodeFormats(inputUri);
            // Allow a sub-set of the hints to be specified by the caller.
            decodeHints = DecodeHintManager.parseDecodeHints(inputUri);

          }

          characterSet = intent.getStringExtra(Intents.Scan.CHARACTER_SET);

        }
      }

      private static boolean isZXingURL(String dataString) {
        if (dataString == null) {
          return false;
        }
        for (String url : ZXING_URLS) {
          if (dataString.startsWith(url)) {
            return true;
          }
        }
        return false;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPause() {
        if (handler != null) {
          handler.quitSynchronously();
          handler = null;
        }
        inactivityTimer.onPause();
        ambientLightManager.stop();
        cameraManager.closeDriver();
        if (!hasSurface) {
          SurfaceView surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.preview_view);
          SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
          surfaceHolder.removeCallback(this);
        }
        super.onPause();
      }

      @Override
      protected void onDestroy() {
        inactivityTimer.shutdown();
        super.onDestroy();
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch (keyCode) {
          case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            if (source == IntentSource.NATIVE_APP_INTENT) {
              setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
              finish();
              return true;
            }
            if ((source == IntentSource.NONE || source == IntentSource.ZXING_LINK) && lastResult != null) {
              restartPreviewAfterDelay(0L);
              return true;
            }
            break;
          case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_FOCUS:
          case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA:
            // Handle these events so they don't launch the Camera app
            return true;
          // Use volume up/down to turn on light
          case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
            cameraManager.setTorch(false);
            return true;
          case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
            cameraManager.setTorch(true);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.capture, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
          case R.id.menu_share:
            intent.setClassName(this, ShareActivity.class.getName());
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
          case R.id.menu_history:
            intent.setClassName(this, HistoryActivity.class.getName());
            startActivityForResult(intent, HISTORY_REQUEST_CODE);
            break;
          case R.id.menu_settings:
            intent.setClassName(this, PreferencesActivity.class.getName());
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
          case R.id.menu_help:
            intent.setClassName(this, HelpActivity.class.getName());
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
          default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return true;
      }

      @Override
      public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
          if (requestCode == HISTORY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            int itemNumber = intent.getIntExtra(Intents.History.ITEM_NUMBER, -1);
            if (itemNumber >= 0) {
              HistoryItem historyItem = historyManager.buildHistoryItem(itemNumber);
              decodeOrStoreSavedBitmap(null, historyItem.getResult());
            }
          }
        }
      }

      private void decodeOrStoreSavedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Result result) {
        // Bitmap isn't used yet -- will be used soon
        if (handler == null) {
          savedResultToShow = result;
        } else {
          if (result != null) {
            savedResultToShow = result;
          }
          if (savedResultToShow != null) {
            Message message = Message.obtain(handler, R.id.decode_succeeded, savedResultToShow);
            handler.sendMessage(message);
          }
          savedResultToShow = null;
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if (holder == null) {
          Log.e(TAG, "*** WARNING *** surfaceCreated() gave us a null surface!");
        }
        if (!hasSurface) {
          hasSurface = true;
          initCamera(holder);
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        hasSurface = false;
      }

      @Override
      public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

      }

      /**
       * A valid barcode has been found, so give an indication of success and show the results.
       *
       * @param rawResult The contents of the barcode.
       * @param scaleFactor amount by which thumbnail was scaled
       * @param barcode   A greyscale bitmap of the camera data which was decoded.
       */
      public void handleDecode(Result rawResult, Bitmap barcode, float scaleFactor) {
        Intent it = getIntent();
        it.putExtra("SCAN_RESULT", rawResult.getText());
        it.putExtra("SCAN_FORMAT", rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString());
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, it);
        finish();

        inactivityTimer.onActivity();
        lastResult = rawResult;
        ResultHandler resultHandler = ResultHandlerFactory.makeResultHandler(this, rawResult);

        boolean fromLiveScan = barcode != null;
        if (fromLiveScan) {
          historyManager.addHistoryItem(rawResult, resultHandler);
          // Then not from history, so beep/vibrate and we have an image to draw on
          beepManager.playBeepSoundAndVibrate();
          drawResultPoints(barcode, scaleFactor, rawResult);
        }

        switch (source) {
          case NATIVE_APP_INTENT:
          case PRODUCT_SEARCH_LINK:
            handleDecodeExternally(rawResult, resultHandler, barcode);
            break;
          case ZXING_LINK:
            if (scanFromWebPageManager == null || !scanFromWebPageManager.isScanFromWebPage()) {
              handleDecodeInternally(rawResult, resultHandler, barcode);
            } else {
              handleDecodeExternally(rawResult, resultHandler, barcode);
            }
            break;
          case NONE:
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            if (fromLiveScan && prefs.getBoolean(PreferencesActivity.KEY_BULK_MODE, false)) {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                             getResources().getString(R.string.msg_bulk_mode_scanned) + " (" + rawResult.getText() + ')',
                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              // Wait a moment or else it will scan the same barcode continuously about 3 times
              restartPreviewAfterDelay(BULK_MODE_SCAN_DELAY_MS);
            } else {
              handleDecodeInternally(rawResult, resultHandler, barcode);
            }
            break;
        }
      }

      /**
       * Superimpose a line for 1D or dots for 2D to highlight the key features of the barcode.
       *
       * @param barcode   A bitmap of the captured image.
       * @param scaleFactor amount by which thumbnail was scaled
       * @param rawResult The decoded results which contains the points to draw.
       */
      private void drawResultPoints(Bitmap barcode, float scaleFactor, Result rawResult) {
        ResultPoint[] points = rawResult.getResultPoints();
        if (points != null && points.length > 0) {
          Canvas canvas = new Canvas(barcode);
          Paint paint = new Paint();
          paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.result_points));
          if (points.length == 2) {
            paint.setStrokeWidth(4.0f);
            drawLine(canvas, paint, points[0], points[1], scaleFactor);
          } else if (points.length == 4 &&
                     (rawResult.getBarcodeFormat() == BarcodeFormat.UPC_A ||
                      rawResult.getBarcodeFormat() == BarcodeFormat.EAN_13)) {
            // Hacky special case -- draw two lines, for the barcode and metadata
            drawLine(canvas, paint, points[0], points[1], scaleFactor);
            drawLine(canvas, paint, points[2], points[3], scaleFactor);
          } else {
            paint.setStrokeWidth(10.0f);
            for (ResultPoint point : points) {
              if (point != null) {
                canvas.drawPoint(scaleFactor * point.getX(), scaleFactor * point.getY(), paint);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

      private static void drawLine(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, ResultPoint a, ResultPoint b, float scaleFactor) {
        if (a != null && b != null) {
          canvas.drawLine(scaleFactor * a.getX(), 
                          scaleFactor * a.getY(), 
                          scaleFactor * b.getX(), 
                          scaleFactor * b.getY(), 
                          paint);
        }
      }

      // Put up our own UI for how to handle the decoded contents.
      private void handleDecodeInternally(Result rawResult, ResultHandler resultHandler, Bitmap barcode) {
        statusView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewfinderView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        resultView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        ImageView barcodeImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.barcode_image_view);
        if (barcode == null) {
          barcodeImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
              R.drawable.launcher_icon));
        } else {
          barcodeImageView.setImageBitmap(barcode);
        }

        TextView formatTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.format_text_view);
        formatTextView.setText(rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString());

        TextView typeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.type_text_view);
        typeTextView.setText(resultHandler.getType().toString());

        DateFormat formatter = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT);
        TextView timeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_text_view);
        timeTextView.setText(formatter.format(new Date(rawResult.getTimestamp())));


        TextView metaTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.meta_text_view);
        View metaTextViewLabel = findViewById(R.id.meta_text_view_label);
        metaTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        metaTextViewLabel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Map<ResultMetadataType,Object> metadata = rawResult.getResultMetadata();
        if (metadata != null) {
          StringBuilder metadataText = new StringBuilder(20);
          for (Map.Entry<ResultMetadataType,Object> entry : metadata.entrySet()) {
            if (DISPLAYABLE_METADATA_TYPES.contains(entry.getKey())) {
              metadataText.append(entry.getValue()).append('\n');
            }
          }
          if (metadataText.length() > 0) {
            metadataText.setLength(metadataText.length() - 1);
            metaTextView.setText(metadataText);
            metaTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            metaTextViewLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          }
        }

        TextView contentsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contents_text_view);
        CharSequence displayContents = resultHandler.getDisplayContents();
        contentsTextView.setText(displayContents);
        // Crudely scale betweeen 22 and 32 -- bigger font for shorter text
        int scaledSize = Math.max(22, 32 - displayContents.length() / 4);
        contentsTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, scaledSize);

        TextView supplementTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contents_supplement_text_view);
        supplementTextView.setText("");
        supplementTextView.setOnClickListener(null);
        if (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean(
            PreferencesActivity.KEY_SUPPLEMENTAL, true)) {
          SupplementalInfoRetriever.maybeInvokeRetrieval(supplementTextView,
                                                         resultHandler.getResult(),
                                                         historyManager,
                                                         this);
        }

        int buttonCount = resultHandler.getButtonCount();
        ViewGroup buttonView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.result_button_view);
        buttonView.requestFocus();
        for (int x = 0; x < ResultHandler.MAX_BUTTON_COUNT; x++) {
          TextView button = (TextView) buttonView.getChildAt(x);
          if (x < buttonCount) {
            button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button.setText(resultHandler.getButtonText(x));
            button.setOnClickListener(new ResultButtonListener(resultHandler, x));
          } else {
            button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          }
        }

        if (copyToClipboard && !resultHandler.areContentsSecure()) {
          ClipboardInterface.setText(displayContents, this);
        }
      }

      // Briefly show the contents of the barcode, then handle the result outside Barcode Scanner.
      private void handleDecodeExternally(Result rawResult, ResultHandler resultHandler, Bitmap barcode) {

        if (barcode != null) {
          viewfinderView.drawResultBitmap(barcode);
        }

        long resultDurationMS;
        if (getIntent() == null) {
          resultDurationMS = DEFAULT_INTENT_RESULT_DURATION_MS;
        } else {
          resultDurationMS = getIntent().getLongExtra(Intents.Scan.RESULT_DISPLAY_DURATION_MS,
                                                      DEFAULT_INTENT_RESULT_DURATION_MS);
        }

        if (resultDurationMS > 0) {
          String rawResultString = String.valueOf(rawResult);
          if (rawResultString.length() > 32) {
            rawResultString = rawResultString.substring(0, 32) + " ...";
          }
          statusView.setText(getString(resultHandler.getDisplayTitle()) + " : " + rawResultString);
        }

        if (copyToClipboard && !resultHandler.areContentsSecure()) {
          CharSequence text = resultHandler.getDisplayContents();
          ClipboardInterface.setText(text, this);
        }

        if (source == IntentSource.NATIVE_APP_INTENT) {

          // Hand back whatever action they requested - this can be changed to Intents.Scan.ACTION when
          // the deprecated intent is retired.
          Intent intent = new Intent(getIntent().getAction());
          intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
          intent.putExtra(Intents.Scan.RESULT, rawResult.toString());
          intent.putExtra(Intents.Scan.RESULT_FORMAT, rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString());
          byte[] rawBytes = rawResult.getRawBytes();
          if (rawBytes != null && rawBytes.length > 0) {
            intent.putExtra(Intents.Scan.RESULT_BYTES, rawBytes);
          }
          Map<ResultMetadataType,?> metadata = rawResult.getResultMetadata();
          if (metadata != null) {
            if (metadata.containsKey(ResultMetadataType.UPC_EAN_EXTENSION)) {
              intent.putExtra(Intents.Scan.RESULT_UPC_EAN_EXTENSION,
                              metadata.get(ResultMetadataType.UPC_EAN_EXTENSION).toString());
            }
            Number orientation = (Number) metadata.get(ResultMetadataType.ORIENTATION);
            if (orientation != null) {
              intent.putExtra(Intents.Scan.RESULT_ORIENTATION, orientation.intValue());
            }
            String ecLevel = (String) metadata.get(ResultMetadataType.ERROR_CORRECTION_LEVEL);
            if (ecLevel != null) {
              intent.putExtra(Intents.Scan.RESULT_ERROR_CORRECTION_LEVEL, ecLevel);
            }
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Iterable<byte[]> byteSegments = (Iterable<byte[]>) metadata.get(ResultMetadataType.BYTE_SEGMENTS);
            if (byteSegments != null) {
              int i = 0;
              for (byte[] byteSegment : byteSegments) {
                intent.putExtra(Intents.Scan.RESULT_BYTE_SEGMENTS_PREFIX + i, byteSegment);
                i++;
              }
            }
          }
          sendReplyMessage(R.id.return_scan_result, intent, resultDurationMS);

        } else if (source == IntentSource.PRODUCT_SEARCH_LINK) {

          // Reformulate the URL which triggered us into a query, so that the request goes to the same
          // TLD as the scan URL.
          int end = sourceUrl.lastIndexOf("/scan");
          String replyURL = sourceUrl.substring(0, end) + "?q=" + resultHandler.getDisplayContents() + "&source=zxing";      
          sendReplyMessage(R.id.launch_product_query, replyURL, resultDurationMS);

        } else if (source == IntentSource.ZXING_LINK) {

          if (scanFromWebPageManager != null && scanFromWebPageManager.isScanFromWebPage()) {
            String replyURL = scanFromWebPageManager.buildReplyURL(rawResult, resultHandler);
            sendReplyMessage(R.id.launch_product_query, replyURL, resultDurationMS);
          }

        }
      }

      private void sendReplyMessage(int id, Object arg, long delayMS) {
        if (handler != null) {
          Message message = Message.obtain(handler, id, arg);
          if (delayMS > 0L) {
            handler.sendMessageDelayed(message, delayMS);
          } else {
            handler.sendMessage(message);
          }
        }
      }

      private void initCamera(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        if (surfaceHolder == null) {
          throw new IllegalStateException("No SurfaceHolder provided");
        }
        if (cameraManager.isOpen()) {
          Log.w(TAG, "initCamera() while already open -- late SurfaceView callback?");
          return;
        }
        try {
          cameraManager.openDriver(surfaceHolder);
          // Creating the handler starts the preview, which can also throw a RuntimeException.
          if (handler == null) {
            handler = new CaptureActivityHandler(this, decodeFormats, decodeHints, characterSet, cameraManager);
          }
          decodeOrStoreSavedBitmap(null, null);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
          Log.w(TAG, ioe);
          displayFrameworkBugMessageAndExit();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
          // Barcode Scanner has seen crashes in the wild of this variety:
          // java.?lang.?RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
          Log.w(TAG, "Unexpected error initializing camera", e);
          displayFrameworkBugMessageAndExit();
        }
      }

      private void displayFrameworkBugMessageAndExit() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.msg_camera_framework_bug));
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.button_ok, new FinishListener(this));
        builder.setOnCancelListener(new FinishListener(this));
        builder.show();
      }

      public void restartPreviewAfterDelay(long delayMS) {
        if (handler != null) {
          handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(R.id.restart_preview, delayMS);
        }
        resetStatusView();
      }

      private void resetStatusView() {
        resultView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        statusView.setText(R.string.msg_default_status);
        statusView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewfinderView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        lastResult = null;
      }

      public void drawViewfinder() {
        viewfinderView.drawViewfinder();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget to include your code.

Comment: The code is ready! @323go

Answer (score 0):

your SplashScreen Java should look like this:

```
{

Intent mainIntent = new Intent().setClass(SplashScreenActivity.this, com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.class);
// use startActivityForResult instead of startActivity
startActivityForResult(mainIntent)

}
```

but I guess you already solved you problem!